# Error "BeanShell 2.0b4 - by Pat Niemeyer (pat@pat.net) bsh%" while running code via eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

on running the below selenium code, i am getting an error in a popup: 
Eclipse version:3.4.2, Selenium stand alone server used:2.51.0
I had the selenium server added to my project. Not sure why this error is popping up

```
package upointPckg;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Upoint {

public static void main(String[] args){

    String url = "www.google.com";
    WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    Driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Driver.get(url);

    }

}
```

Also tried running it without importing the drivers, it shows the same error:

```
package uPointPackage;

public class UPointClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "www.google.com";
        System.out.println(url);

    }

}
```

---

Comment: Show the error message.

Comment: I'd say some kind of Eclipse misconfiguration. What 'Run Configuration' are you using? Should be 'Java Application'. Check that the config hasn't got BeanShell stuff mixed up in there.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

BeanShell 2.0b4 - by Pat Niemeyer (pat@pat.net)

Hi Guys, I was also getting same error because i had mentioned `main()` method within multiple classes under same package. So while executing current class from run icon at header in eclipse, compiler was getting confused to which `main()` method need to be executed.

So solution is to write `main()` method only in single class within a `package` or `execute` only single class by `right click` on that particular class and run as Java Application,